# Merge In Place Multiple JSON Files- Golang

Tags: go

I have multiple files segments, each contains a JSON of slice of NameStrct (the slice is already sorted by field Timestamp).

```
type NameStrct Struct{
     Name String
     Timestamp time.Time
}
```

I need to create a service in GO that when it receives time period it returns a single JSON file with a sorted slice containing all NameStrct with Timestamp at that period.

The naive approach is have the service download all the files into disk, read and unmarshal them, append them into one big slice, sort it, marshal it to a single file and send it.

But the issue is there are too many files, and reading them all into memory is not possible.
Is there some sort of a way I can append and sort all the files in place without reading them to memory?
Is there a better approach to do this?
Thank you

Comment: So you receive files with sorted slices, and you want to sort them "globally" again? Do I get this right? If you can't sort all these structs in memory, you can ofc. still sort them on the hard disc, simulating the operations which would take in the RAM normally, storing some metadata in another file if need be. But this sounds not very efficient ... did you think about writing them into a database? You can sort them there easily and even paginate in case it's too much.

Comment: This is a tipical problem where you might use the map reduce approach. Anyway you don't need to have all the files in memory at the same time, go routine's number can be limited according to the available memory, so even map reduce is not needed.